# Amazon SES not working from Rackspace Servers

Tags: smtp, amazon-web-services, rackspace

Has anyone encountered a problem where they cannot connect to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com for SMTP from a Rackspace server? WHen I ping from a rackspace server there is always 100% packet loss. So I ran a trace route and this was the result.

```
[root@job-server-1 ~]# traceroute email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
traceroute to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (xx.xxx.47.187), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  162.209.11.2 (162.209.11.2)  3.710 ms  3.781 ms  3.752 ms
 2  core5-aggr1501a-4.ord1.rackspace.net (50.56.6.56)  4.681 ms  4.627 ms  4.604 ms
 3  50.56.6.130 (50.56.6.130)  4.544 ms  4.528 ms 50.56.6.128 (50.56.6.128)  4.506 ms
 4  edge3.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.141)  5.273 ms edge3.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.143)  5.236 ms edge3.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.141)  5.208 ms
 5  xe-3-2-0.er1.ord7.us.above.net (64.124.65.217)  5.184 ms  5.159 ms  5.129 ms
 6  xe-2-2-0.cr1.ord2.us.above.net (64.125.26.249)  6.643 ms  2.015 ms  4.399 ms
 7  xe-5-0-0.cr1.lga5.us.above.net (64.125.31.238)  24.311 ms  24.274 ms  24.268 ms
 8  xe-3-2-0.cr1.dca2.us.above.net (64.125.26.101)  26.449 ms  26.422 ms  26.408 ms
 9  xe-3-2-0.er1.iad10.us.above.net (64.125.29.209)  26.384 ms  26.352 ms  26.335 ms
10  xe-1-0-0.er5.iad10.us.above.net (64.125.24.133)  25.768 ms  25.742 ms  25.707 ms
11  above-amazon.iad10.us.above.net (64.125.12.30)  29.229 ms  28.451 ms  28.405 ms
12  72.21.220.63 (72.21.220.63)  29.107 ms  28.792 ms  28.756 ms
13  72.21.222.155 (72.21.222.155)  29.143 ms  30.465 ms  30.441 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  216.182.224.229 (216.182.224.229)  24.664 ms  24.610 ms 216.182.224.91 (216.182.224.91)  23.864 ms
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Has anyone had this problem before and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though ICMP is blocked on the SES servers, so pings and traceroutes won't work regardless of where you do it from.  However, my tests to connect to SMTP on the host you provided works fine from a Rackspace Cloud Server:

```
$ echo quit | nc -v email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25
Connection to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-376766033
```

Comment: That is very weird, because trying to connect to it using SMTP over ssl or tsl does not work.

Comment: That also doesn't explain why from my local, if I ping it, I get packets back, but not from a server instance